# Is there any API for getting start time of a APACHE WebServer?

Tags: c++, apache, apache2, webserver, diagnostics

I am writing a small application to get the various diagnostic parameter of Apache Webserver like time of the start of the server, [Worker mode](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/worker.html) or [Prefork mode](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html), server version and many more. I have found few API for getting info about these parameter. But I colud not find nay API for the getting start time of the WebServer. Is there any such kind of API?
If there is no API then there are different approaches like getting the start time using "ps" command in linux/unix and go for similar API in windows.There can be other approach that I could see is to have the time of the APache WebServer in any Variable or file. 
Please enlighten me with your valuable comments, approaches.

TIA
Anil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to have a look at the Apache' the [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html)

Comment: You are welcome.
Don't forget to accept the answer if you think that answered to your question.